# how to rewrite a specifiq url by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change the URL from:

```
http://domain.com/blog/contact
```

to:

```
http://domain.com/contact
```

Here, http://domain.com: is a simple static site, and for blogging and contact page we have used wordpress as a subfolder(blog), that is the cause we are getting `http://domain.com/blog/contact`. So for blogging page it is opening blog from this `http://domain.com/blog` url. And it is ok. But in contact page  we want to change the url like  `http://domain.com/contact` instead of `http://domain.com/blog/contact`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this `RewriteRule`, make sure you clear your cache before testing it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)/blog/(.*) $1/$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your .htaccess file under **SUBDIRECTORY**, OR create new .htaccess file to manage the redirection.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

OR instead of above add following code to your root .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Clear the cache or try another browser